# Jquery submit() doesn't pass file data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple form.

```
<form name="text_hero" id="text_hero" action="<?php echo site_url('templates/saveImage/texthero'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
    <input type="submit" value"submit file">
</form>
```

When pressing the submit button the file is uploaded correctly and saves.

When using Jquery to either "click" the submit button or manually submit the form it fails to send the file.

Jquery:

```
$('#' + FormName).submit();
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for this?

EDIT

When outputting the php $_FILES var it just outputs Array() with the jquery method but with the button method it outputs the actual file.

Comment: How does it fails exactly? Could you be more accurate?

Comment: Please post your php or whatever code that handles the upload

Comment: Also, where do you have that code to submit?

Comment: sounds  like you are trying to upload files with ajax, which doesn't work...show  more code

Comment: @DanGoodspeed that doesn't explain differnces received by `$_FILES`...which is what makes me think ajax... can trigger submit and still have ajax withing the actual handler

Answer (score 0):

**About**

When you do some upload of files you need put on form this `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

**Example:**

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

To save the tmp_file to some file

you need put some validation but the basic upload some file is this.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'path/to/file');
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: his form does have that, scroll the code window to the right.